# CakePHP - Saving HABTM

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
// Models/Tables with HABTM:
companies, sectors, companies_sectors

// Controller
$sectors = $this->Sector->find('list', array('fields'=>array('Sector.id', 'Sector.sector')));

// View
echo $this->Form->input('Sector.id', array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $sectors,
));

// Posted 
$this->request->data = array(
'Company' => array(
    'id' => '177',
    'company_name' => 'Testing Co',
),
'Sector' => array(
    'id' => array(
        (int) 0 => '2',
        (int) 1 => '3'
    )
));

// Controller
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    // This saves the data into the 'companies' table just fine - but that's it
    $this->Company->save($this->request->data);
    
    // Tried this
    $this->Company->Sector->save($this->request->data);
    
    /* Get this error
     Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
     SQL Query: UPDATE `h_dev`.`sectors` SET `id` = Array WHERE `h_dev`.`sectors`.`id` = '2' 
    */
    
    // Tried this - does nothing
    foreach ($this->request->data['Sector']['id'] as $id)
    {
        // made sure $this->Company->id is set from previous save()
        $this->Company->Sector->create();
        $this->Company->Sector->save(array('company_id'=>$this->Company->id, 'sector_id'=>$id));
    }
}
```

How do I save this request->data correctly into all HABTM tables?

Comment: Did you read the following link in the official documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm

Comment: Yes, the challenge is saving an array of ids.
`'Sector' => array(
    'id' => array(
        (int) 0 => '2',
        (int) 1 => '3'
    )
)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for saving data $this->Model->saveAssociated($data);
[CakePHP Model saveAssociated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array)

Comment: The saveAssociated() method did not work for me. Again, it did not like the array of IDs. What did work for me was looping through the array of IDs and rebuilding the array to be associated, and then did a saveAll() on that new array. I think there's a better way of doing this - more CakePHPish, I just don't know how that is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the relationships setup correctly in your models? You need to make sure that you have the HABTM in both `Company` and `Sectors`. Also be certain that your database table for the HABTM is named correctly: `companies_sectors`